# Submit form text if the user inputs the 3rd value

Tags: javascript, html

i got a textbox here

```
<input type="test" name="search" oninput="submitForm()" autocomplete="off">
```

and a javascript code

```
<script>
function submitForm(){
document.getElementById("testform").submit();
}

$("#aw").focus();
</script>
```

the problem here is that when i enter the first value it submits right away. how can i submit form when the user entered the 3rd text value.

Comment: mmm...just a a raw logic,place a counter in JS and when its 3, submit!!!

Comment: I think you maybe mean when the user inputs the third _character_, i.e. the value of the input field reaches a length of 3 …?

Comment: but i think counter is not viable since because the counter also counts if u press spacebar and backspace :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the counter, when it will reaches to 3, then submit the form.

```
var textNumber = 0;
function submitForm(){
    textNumber++;
    if(textNumber == 3){
        document.getElementById("testform").submit();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

We can't get keycode on `oninput` event to handle *whitespace* and *backspace*, so if you can use `keypress` event

```
<input ID="mySearch" type="test" name="search" autocomplete="off">
$("#mySearch").on('keypress', submitForm);
function submitForm(e){
   if(e.which != 32){  //for space, not fired when backspace is pressed
      textNumber++;
      if(textNumber == 3){
          document.getElementById("testform").submit();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: it solves my question, but i think counter is not viable since because the counter also counts if u press spacebar and backspace :/

Comment: Can you use the `keypress` event?

Comment: please have a look updated answer iwth keypress event.

Comment: Count the length value of the textbox, not a counter on every keystroke. Then you just use a split or something to remove spaces if you want.

Comment: @Casey, OP wants to submit form on type of 3rr character. It does not help from what you said.

Comment: Oh, I thought he wanted to submit the form after the values were placed in the text field. I have done this before by counting the length of the value to make sure it was three characters. I guess I misunderstood the question. My bad.